Do we abandon doing mediation analysis if the correlations between the moderators and IVs and DVs are not statistically significant?
Suppose that I have an a research question that is best answered by a mediation analysis. However, after running a correlation analysis, there are no significant correlations between the mediator variable and the IV and DV. Do I just abandon doing the mediation analysis?
How can I proceed with answering the research question?

Mediation analysis tests for the presence of an indirect effect. None of the associations you mentioned correspond to the indirect effect, so none of them answer your research question. You should not decide to run a test based on the results of another test; doing so invalidates the inference made from the latter test. If your research question requires a mediation analysis, run the analysis.
